How to count if a product is bought on the same day, by the same person, together with another product?
I've been browsing multiple different places to try and find an answer but I think I'm likely too thick and/or over simplifying how Excel works.
What I'm trying to get is hopefully a matrix, unless there is a better way where I can see in this example, how many times a product has been bought on the same day, by the same customer together with another product.
This is what the data looks like:




A
B
C




1
Client Name
Booking Date
Product Name


2
John
2/26/2024
Product 1


3
John
2/26/2024
Product 1


4
John
2/26/2024
Product 2


5
John
2/26/2024
Product 3


6
John
2/26/2024
Product 4


7
John
3/30/2024
Product 1


8
John
4/11/2024
Product 2


9
John
4/11/2024
Product 3


10
Dave
6/24/2024
Product 3


11
Dave
6/24/2024
Product 1


12
Dave
6/24/2024
Product 3


13
Dave
6/24/2024
Product 1


14
Dave
7/17/2024
Product 2


15
Dave
7/17/2024
Product 1


16
Bob
6/6/2024
Product 1


17
Bob
6/6/2024
Product 2


18
Bob
6/8/2024
Product 2


19
Bob
6/8/2024
Product 3



I've tried to implement various countifs and xlookups to no real avail, and I'm starting to think I'm asking too much.
This is how I expect the outcome to be:



1

Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 4




2
Product 1
2
3
2
1


3
Product 2
3
0
3
1


4
Product 3
2
3
1
1


5
Product 4
1
1
1
0



Explanation of the outcome for Product 2:
1st buy:
John 2/26/2024 together with: Product 1 (twice, but counts as 1x together), not together with Product 2 (it needs to be more than 1 of itself to count as together with), together with Product 3 and together with Product 4.
This counts as {1,0,1,1}.
2nd buy:
John 4/11/2024 together with: Product 1, no; Product 2; no, Product 3, yes, Product 4, no.
This counts as {0,0,1,0}.
3rd buy:
Dave 7/17/2024 together with: Product 1, yes; Product 2, no, 3 & 4, no.
This counts as {1,0,0,0}.
4th buy:
Bob 6/6/2024 together with: 1, yes; 2, no; 3, no; 4, no.
This counts as {1,0,0,0}.
5th (last) buy:
Bob 6/8/2024 together with: 1, no; 2, no; 3, yes; 4, no.
This counts as {0,0,1,0}.
Summed by column (product) makes: {3,0,3,1}
Any way around this that isn't overtly complex, does this request make sense?? Thank you!

It's possible, but not easy (thanks for the challenge!):
=LET(data,A2:C19, ab,TAKE(data,,1)&INDEX(data,,2), c,DROP(data,,2), u,UNIQUE(c),
REDUCE(HSTACK("",TOROW(u)), u,
       LAMBDA(d,e,
       LET(f,FILTER(HSTACK(data,ab),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(ab,FILTER(ab,c=e)))),
           r,IFNA(REDUCE(0, UNIQUE(INDEX(f,,4)),
                  LAMBDA(x,y,
                  LET(z,FILTER(INDEX(f,,3),INDEX(f,,4)=y),
                      s,UNIQUE(DROP(SORTBY(z,INDEX(z,,1)<>e),1)),
                      VSTACK(x,
                             IFERROR(MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(s),,0),N(s=TOROW(u))),0))))),0),
       VSTACK(d,
              HSTACK(e, BYCOL(r,SUM)))))))

This loops through the unique products e, filters name & date & product rows where the product column contains the current product e.
Next it loops through the unique name & dates and adds 1 to the product's count if it was bought together with current product e (where 1 bought of e does not count as together).

I figured this could be simplified (I think) a bit using MAKEARRAY:
=LET(a,A2:A19, b,B2:B19, c,C2:C19, p,UNIQUE(c), n,ROWS(p),
VSTACK(HSTACK("",
              TOROW(p)),
       HSTACK(p,
              MAKEARRAY(n,n,LAMBDA(v,w,
                    LET(z,INDEX(p,v),
                        SUM(BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(a&b,c=z)),LAMBDA(x,LET(f,FILTER(c,1-ISNA(XMATCH(a&b,x))),SUM(N(IFERROR(UNIQUE(DROP(SORTBY(f,f<>z),1)),"")=INDEX(p,w)))))))))))))

(probably more user friendly:)
=LET(client,A2:A19,
     booking,B2:B19,
     product,C2:C19,
     uniqueproduct,UNIQUE(product),
     unqprodrows,ROWS(uniqueproduct),
VSTACK(
       HSTACK("",
              TOROW(uniqueproduct)),
       HSTACK(uniqueproduct,
              MAKEARRAY(unqprodrows,     unqprodrows,
                 LAMBDA(verticalcounter, horizontalcounter,
                    LET(currentrowproduct,INDEX(uniqueproduct,verticalcounter),
                        SUM( BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(client&booking,product=currentrowproduct)),
                            LAMBDA(nthbuy,
                               LET(nthbuyfilterincludingself,FILTER(product,1-ISNA(XMATCH(client&booking,nthbuy))),
                                   SUM(
                                       N(IFERROR( UNIQUE(DROP(SORTBY(nthbuyfilterincludingself,nthbuyfilterincludingself<>currentrowproduct),1)) ,"")
                                         =INDEX(uniqueproduct,horizontalcounter)))))))))))))


I'm glad you enjoyed the challenge. I've used some of these terms in Excel before probably a long time ago so it's definitely taking some time to wrap my head around it but once I know what I need to ask I'll come back.

I'm attempting a simple-minded solution to this thinking maybe you can use countifs after all. This seems to work for the off-diagonal elements:
=LET(
    date,$B$2:$B$19,
    Product,$C$2:$C$19,
    SUM((COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,G$1)>0)*(COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,$E2)>0)/COUNTIF(date,date)))


Then the on-diagonal elements would just be:
=LET(
date,$B$2:$B$19,
Product,$C$2:$C$19,
SUM((COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,F$1)>1)/COUNTIF(date,date)))


You can put these two formulas together or put them into a Map or Makearray.
=LET(
date,B2:B19,
Product,C2:C19,
ProdList,F1:I1,
MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,
LET(P_1,INDEX(ProdList,r),P_2,INDEX(ProdList,c),
IF(r=c,
   SUM((COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,P_1)>1)/COUNTIF(date,date)), 
   SUM((COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,P_1)>0)*(COUNTIFS(date,date,Product,P_2)>0)/COUNTIF(date,date))))))
)


I like it. I do think you need another argument on the names, but that's not hard

=LET(name,A2:A19,date,B2:B19,Product,C2:C19,ProdList,TOROW(UNIQUE(C2:C19)),MAKEARRAY(4,4,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(P_1,INDEX(ProdList,r),P_2,INDEX(ProdList,c),IF(r=c,   SUM((COUNTIFS(name,name,date,date,Product,P_1)>1)/COUNTIFS(name,name,date,date)),   SUM((COUNTIFS(name,name,date,date,Product,P_1)>0)*(COUNTIFS(name,name,date,date,Product,P_2)>0)/COUNTIFS(name,name,date,date)))))))

You're quite right, I was a bit lazy in assuming there would be no cases of same date with different name.
